# how to sleep on the address of a variable and get waken up when the variable value is changed

Tags: linux, synchronization, cross-platform, freebsd

It's for purpose of synchronization among two different OSes. 
There is a shared memory served as the only communication channel for OS A and B, let's say Linux and BSD. Now a process in Linux would like to get notified when the shared memory is changed by BSD, then the process will read the contents and handle it.

It's similar to function futex in Linux,

`int futex(int *uaddr, int op, int val, const struct timespec *timeout,
                 int *uaddr2, int val3)`

or tsleep in FreeBSD,

`tsleep(void *chan, int priority, const char *wmesg, int timo)`

The difference is, the sleeping process is not waken up by explicitly calling wakeup() method, but only to change the content on the sleeping address.

is there any such functions?

Comment: How are two different OSes sharing memory? Are they virtual machines?

Comment: A Virtual Machine Monitor(VMM) beneath the two OSes will handle the memory mapping. Given Linux allocates a block of memory and tells VMM the starting virtual address, then the VMM can translate it into host physical address and map to guest physical address for BSD. Then BSD can get the gpa and map it gva.

Comment: Have you considered using server sockets instead of shared memory? I don't have a clue about what you're doing, but it may be easier to implement this in a different way.